# iterate through 8 thermocouple sensors (MAX31856)

Tags: adafruit, array

I have 8xMAX31856 and I am trying to use the Adafruit library. Instead of writing all 8 thermocouple channels each time in code (and wasting memory), I want to store the objects in an array and loop through them periodically.

Here is my code:

```
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple1 = Adafruit_MAX31856(2,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple2 = Adafruit_MAX31856(3,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple3 = Adafruit_MAX31856(4,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple4 = Adafruit_MAX31856(5,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple5 = Adafruit_MAX31856(6,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple6 = Adafruit_MAX31856(7,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple7 = Adafruit_MAX31856(8,11,12,13);
Adafruit_MAX31856 TCouple8 = Adafruit_MAX31856(9,11,12,13);

char* thermocouples[] = {TCouple1, TCouple2, TCouple3, TCouple4, TCouple5, TCouple6, TCouple7, TCouple8};
```

however, I am met with this error on compile:

```
cannot convert 'Adafruit_MAX31856' to 'char*' in initialization
```

Why can I not store these variables in an array and call on them later? Is there another way to do this? They work on SPI logic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN store them in an array, but NOT in an array of pointers to characters. That is just the wrong type. Try

```
Adafruit_MAX31856 thermocouples[] = {TCouple1, ...}
```

or even ditch the first declarations and use

```
Adafruit_MAX31856 thermocouples[] = {
    Adafruit_MAX31856(2,11,12,13),
    Adafruit_MAX31856(3,11,12,13),
    Adafruit_MAX31856(4,11,12,13),
    ...
};
```

I don't have that library installed, but I tried compiling this pattern with the `Bounce2` library and it works. That looks like this:

```
Bounce buttons[] = {
    Bounce(),
    Bounce(),
    Bounce()
};
```

Comment: Alright! I have tried that and it compiles past it... but how do I loop through this array? I tried `for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){thermocouples[i].setThermocoupleType(MAX31856_TCTYPE_T);}` and it says it is `void`

Comment: nevermind... sorted out issue. Thanks for the guidance!